# Remove child in XML with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a XML file like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\XYZ.MyAPP.EntityModel\AppContext.cs" Link="AppContext.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I want to remove `<ItemGroup>` where `<ItemGroup>` has an attribute "Link".
Notice: there may be multiple `<ItemGroup>` nodes (like in this example) with multiple occurincies or without attribute "Link".

I tried something like this:

```bsh
[Xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path .\XYZ.MyApp.Model.csproj 
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//Project/ItemGroup")

foreach ($node in $nodes) {
    if ($node.HasChildNodes) {
        foreach ($child in $node.ChildNodes) {
            if ($child.Name -eq "Compile") {
                Write-Host "BINGO"
                $child.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild("//Project/ItemGroup")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice: this code doesn't work. I am getting an error:

> Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "//Project/ItemGroup", for "RemoveChild" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode": "Cannot convert the "//Project/ItemGroup" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Xml.XmlNode"."

**Goal**: Find all `<ItemGroup>` nodes and removes only those who has Link attribute.

Comment: The XPath expression for selecting only nodes that have an attribute `Link` is `//*[@Link]`. The XPath expression for selecting only nodes with a *child node* that has an attribute `Link` is `//*[./*/@Link]` or just `//*[*/@Link]`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks. And what would be the xPath for putting and name? If I want to select node that contains the Name:Compile and the attribute Link? something like `//*/Compile[@Link]`?

Comment: Replace the wildcard `*` with the name of a specific node for making an expression more specific (e.g. `//*[Compile/@Link]`). For further help please check Microsoft's [XPath Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(v=vs.110).aspx).